# TypeError: parse_pm_order_operations_dl() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to parse a nested json file which has a one to many relationship output. When running my code i get the error message: "TypeError: parse__dl() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given:

See code below for current work done:

```
    def parse_lines(self, s3obj, file_content):
        """
        Parse each line ifof the file and append the parsed data to the corresponding table'
        Args:
            s3obj (objcet): Object that represents an object in an s3 bucket (file or dir)
            file_content (str): Contents of a file.

        Return:
               dict: A dictionary with keys as table names and values as a listof parsed data for each table.   
        """
        records = {
            self.table_names[self. te_pm_order_operations_dl]: []
        }

        for line in file_content:
            try:
                record = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.exception('Error processing record %s.', line)
                raise e

            operations_dl = self.parse_pm_order_operations_dl(s3obj, record)
            if not operations_dl:
                print()
            else:
                records[self.table_names[self.te_pm_order_operations_dl]].append(operations_dl)
        return records

    def parse_pm_order_operations_dl(self, record, response):
        metadata = record.get('metadata')
        payload = record.get('payload')
        try:
            plantMaintenanceOrderOperations = payload.get("plantMaintenanceOrderOperations"),

        except:
            return {}

        if not plantMaintenanceOrderOperations:
            return {}
        
        try:
            plantMaintenanceOrderOperations = json.loads(plantMaintenanceOrderOperations)
        except:
            return {}

        result = []
        for idx, item in enumerate(plantMaintenanceOrderOperations):
            idx = metadata.copy()
            idx.update({

                  'operationStandardTextKey': item["operationStandardTextKey"],
                  'operationActivityNumber': convert_to_int(item["operationActivityNumber"]),
                  'operationDescription': item["operationDescription"],
                  'operationStatusSystem': item["operationStatusSystem"],
                  'operationStatusUser': item["operationStatusUser"],
                  'operationConfirmationNumber': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsActualData"]["operationConfirmationNumber"],
                  'operationActualWork': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsActualData"]["operationActualWork"],
                  'operationEarliestScheduledStartTimestamp': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationEarliestScheduledStartTimestamp"],
                  'operationConstraintFinishTimestamp': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintFinishTimestamp"],
                  'operationLatestScheduledStartTimestamp': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationLatestScheduledStartTimestamp"],
                  'operationEarliestScheduledStartTime': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationEarliestScheduledStartTime"],
                  'operationEarliestScheduledFinishTime': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationEarliestScheduledFinishTime"],
                  'operationConstraintFinishTime': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintFinishTime"],
                  'operationConstraintStartTime': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintStartTime"],
                  'operationLatestScheduledFinishTimestamp': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationLatestScheduledFinishTimestamp"],
                  'operationEarliestScheduledStartDate': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationEarliestScheduledStartDate"],
                  'operationConstraintFinishType': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintFinishType"],
                  'operationLatestScheduledStartDate': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationLatestScheduledStartDate"],
                  'operationEarliestScheduledFinishTimestamp': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationEarliestScheduledFinishTimestamp"],
                  'operationConstraintStartDate': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintStartDate"],
                  'operationEarliestScheduledFinishDate': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationEarliestScheduledFinishDate"],
                  'operationLatestScheduledFinishTime': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationLatestScheduledFinishTime"],
                  'operationConstraintStartType': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintStartType"],
                  'operationConstraintStartTimestamp': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintStartTimestamp"],
                  'operationLatestScheduledStartTime': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationLatestScheduledStartTime"],
                  'operationLatestScheduledFinishDate': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationLatestScheduledFinishDate"],
                  'operationConstraintFinishDate': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates"]["operationConstraintFinishDate"],
                  'operationWorkCenterId': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationWorkCenterId"],
                  'operationWorkCenterDescription': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationWorkCenterDescription"],
                  'operationWorkCenterPlantId': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationWorkCenterPlantId"],
                  'operationControKey': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationControKey"],
                  'operationActivityType': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationActivityType"],
                  'operationWorkActivity': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationWorkActivity"],
                  'operationNumberOfWorkers': convert_to_int(item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationNumberOfWorkers"]),
                  'operationDuration': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationDuration"],
                  'operationPersonalNumber': item["plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal"]["operationPersonalNumber"],      
                  'p_date':  get_current_date(),
                  'p_hour': get_current_hour()
            })
            result.append(idx)
        return result
```

With the json file output composed of:

```
"plantMaintenanceOrderOperations": [
      {
        "operationStandardTextKey": "",
        "plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsActualData": {
          "operationActualWork": "P0Y0M0DT16H30M0S",
          "operationConfirmationNumber": "0004176909"
        },
        "operationDescription": "Test oData Test",
        "plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsDates": {
          "operationEarliestScheduledStartTimestamp": "2022-11-30T06:57:08.000+01:00",
          "operationConstraintFinishTimestamp": "",
          "operationLatestScheduledStartTimestamp": "2022-11-30T06:57:08.000+01:00",
          "operationEarliestScheduledStartTime": "07:57:08",
          "operationEarliestScheduledFinishTime": "23:45:14",
          "operationConstraintFinishTime": "00:00:00",
          "operationConstraintStartTime": "00:00:00",
          "operationLatestScheduledFinishTimestamp": "2022-12-08T22:45:14.000+01:00",
          "operationEarliestScheduledStartDate": "2022-11-30",
          "operationConstraintFinishType": "",
          "operationLatestScheduledStartDate": "2022-11-30",
          "operationEarliestScheduledFinishTimestamp": "2022-12-08T22:45:14.000+01:00",
          "operationConstraintStartDate": "0000-00-00",
          "operationEarliestScheduledFinishDate": "2022-12-08",
          "operationLatestScheduledFinishTime": "23:45:14",
          "operationConstraintStartType": "",
          "operationConstraintStartTimestamp": "",
          "operationLatestScheduledStartTime": "07:57:08",
          "operationLatestScheduledFinishDate": "2022-12-08",
          "operationConstraintFinishDate": "0000-00-00"
        },
        "operationStatusUser": "",
        "operationActivityNumber": "0010",
        "operationStatusSystem": "CNF  REL",
        "plantMaintenanceOrderOperationsInternal": {
          "operationWorkCenterDescription": "",
          "operationWorkCenterPlantId": "A120",
          "operationPersonalNumber": "00000000",
          "operationWorkCenterId": "IH-MVK",
          "operationDuration": "",
          "operationNumberOfWorkers": 0,
          "operationActivityType": "S4622",
          "operationControKey": "ZIHE",
          "operationWorkActivity": ""
        }
      }
    ]
```

Any assitence on how i add the 3rd element would be greatly appreiated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I take a guess on your problem :)

"takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

```
def foo(element1, element2): #expecting 2 args
    doSomeThing()

foo(element1, element2, element3) # would result in the error, because of 3 args
```

you could fix this via *args

```
def foo(*elements): 
    doSomeThing()
    print(elements) # list of args [element1, element2, element3]

foo(element1, element2, element3)
```

edit:

other option:

```
def foo(element1, element2) #expecting 2 args
    doSomeThing()

foo(element1, [element2, element3]) # passing 2 args: element1 and a list containing element2 and element3
```